Why is the double dot(parent directory) acting weird with the bin folder?
I started studying bash from the very beginning. I decided to practice using shortcuts for the current directory and the parent directory (dot and double dot). I noticed some strange behavior of the latter with the bin folder. To show this strangeness, I will first show how it works with home directory, and then how it works with bin.

Let's output the contents of the root folder

I start practicing. We go to the home folder, then back, and it turns out to be the root folder again.(Works as expected)
But for some reason the same thing doesn't work with the Bin folder. It does not show the contents of the root directory, as in the cases above. 
EDT: I've tried 'cd bin/..' and 'cd bin/../..' and in both cases 'pwd' says i'm in '/', but why is ls's output diffent?
And to make it work you have to go back twice.

Like the home directory, directories etc, mnt, boot work correctly. But bin does not.
Can someone explain why this is?

You can't go deeper than /. /bin is at the top level. /bin/.. makes no sense. There's nothing unexpected

If you want to test .., do: cd /usr/share/bash-completion/; pwd; ls then cd ..; pwd; ls

@GillesQuénot, i thought '/' is first level and 'bin' is second

@GillesQuénot Not sure I understand the first of your comment (the 2nd is clear). /bin/.. is just /, or would be, if /bin wasn't a symlink. /bin is a directory, and not the root one (link or not), so it has a .., so /bin/.. makes sense. It is /.. that makes non sense. Or /bin/../.. if /bin was really a top level (which I pretty sure it is not)

i thought '/' is first level and 'bin' is second, no, '/' is the top level and bin, opt, usr, .... live at the top level. The 2nd level is after you cd into a directory. Third, cd into another child directory, etc.

@shellter I agree that the initial intend of OP was clearly to ask about some Unix usage, not about actual programming (not even programming in bash language). This is quite common: lot of people confuse tag bash with "anything geeky that I do in a terminal", and use it to ask some "unix&linux" question. But it turned out that the main difficulties here was cd behavior. And that is bash not unix. Not big bash code with for loop and stuff. But still, bash. So that is of interest to bash coder. They need to know what cd does. And cd is part of bash language, not unix command :-)

@chrslg : All right, I accept that idea and removing my v-2-cls. Leaving my remark here about a very well written first(ish) question.

See Understanding directory symlinks traversals and the parent directory.

Also see With symbolic links, why are the results from "ls .." and "cd .. " different?.

/bin is probably a symbolic link to /usr/bin. At least it is a link to somewhere. But since I know some unix system have /bin be a symlink to /usr/bin, plus the fact that the content of your displayed /bin/.. is the same as /usr on my machine (on which there is no such symlink tho, but on my previous arch, there was).
So, have a look at ls -ld /bin
You'll see that it is a link to /usr/bin or to ../usr/bin.
So /bin/.. is really /usr/bin/.. that is /usr
Just an experiment
(An experiment to show that this would be exactly what happen if /bin was a symlink to /usr/bin)
Set up some mock tree (I use capital for directories, and touch a file that shows full (full from my mock root Tmp) path each dir)
mkdir Tmp
touch Tmp/root
mkdir Tmp/Usr
touch Tmp/Usr/usr
mkdir Tmp/Usr/Bin
touch Tmp/Usr/Bin/usr.bin
cd Tmp
ln -s Usr/Bin Bin
cd ..

From there we can see that
ls -ld Tmp/Bin

is a link (obviously, since I made it that way. Just since you discover all that, want to make clear that this is what your saw on your actual system) : Tmp/Bin -> Usr/Bin
And therefore that
ls Tmp/Bin/..

shows
Bin  usr

That is the content of Tmp/Usr, not the one of Tmp (that would be root)
cd different behaviour
But, indeed
cd Tmp/bin/..
ls

shows
Bin  root  Usr

That is the content of Tmp not Tmp/Usr, as if Tmp/Bin parent were Tmp
why ?
As for why, it is important to understand that cd is not a program (unlike ls, cp, etc.). It is a shell command. So it can have a different (in this case, documented), behaviour. Well, theoretically, any program can have its own interpretation of those ..; what they are passed is just a string, such as bin/.., what they do with it, is up to them. But most would do just a open or opendir , with that string argument, and that would lead bin/.. to be interpreted as you have seen ls do.
cd acts differently, as the documentation says (man bash)

If  .. appears in dir, it is processed by removing the immediately previous pathname component from dir

In other words, cd foo/bar/bla/.. means cd foo/bar whatever those are in reality. Especially, if bla is a symlink to a different place far for foo/bar, it doesn't matter. cd process first, transparently, without even caring what the filesystem have to say about those (or even if they make any sense from the filesystum point of view. It is just some string processing), is to remove any .. and what immediately precedes it, from the chain of / separated substring. And then, and only then, it starts to bother with reality of filesystem.
You can force it, tho, to act as another command would do, that is to resolve what is really foo/bar/bla/.. or Tmp/Bin/.. or /bin/.., by using option -P

The -P option causes cd to use the  physical  directory
structure  by resolving symbolic links while traversing dir
and before processing instances of .. in dir

cd -P Tmp/Bin/..
ls

shows indeed
Bin  usr

as you were expecting (that is what ls Tmp/Bin/.. would show
Ok but why ?
Lastly, the reason of that choice from cd, frankly I have no idea. What I know is that unix system call chdir (man 2 chdir) does behave like the bash command with -P flag. So reason is not a Unix reason. More a bash choice.
For example, tcsh (another shell. The one that was quite standard when I learned Unix, and still exists today) acts differently
$ tcsh
> cd Tmp/Bin/..
> ls

shows
Bin  usr

(Note that I use ls and my touched files to know where cd goes. Obviously pwd is the tool to know where I am. I do so only because your initial question was about ls)
So, different shells, different behavior. This is not a Unix thing, but a bash thing (and sh, and zsh, ...)

I don't know anything about links yet, but it seems you're right: it outputs "/bin -> usr/bin". But the question still remains.  Can you look at the edited part of the paragraph again? Why does the cd command behave one way(says i'm in root) and ls another(prints usr folder and root)?

I edited my post to answer that other question (and also to remove my argument about why I am pretty sure that my hypothesis wasn't that silly, since in the meantime you confirmed that it was true, and the downvote was cancelled)
